# Posting a question to stack overflow gives me a "dirty" form

Tags: bug, asking-questions

Earlier today, I posted a question to stackoverflow.  Later, I went to post another question.  When I clicked "Ask Question", instead of giving me a blank question page, it gave me a page that was pre-filled with the subject line, body, and tags from my previous question.  If I post, will it overwrite my last question?

Comment: Is it possible you started the question in one browser or on one machine and you submitted it from another?

Comment: Nope -- same machine.  Possibly the same instance of IE.  (I tried closing IE and then asking the question again -- I got the same results).

Comment: Ok.  Weirder. I tried asking my second question using Chrome.  I had to login (yes, my primary browser is IE 9, I'm weird like that).  Still, when I clicked Ask Question, it pre-filled with my earlier question.

Comment: You could always try and see. The worst thing that could happen if it did overwrite your last question is you'd have to rollback an edit. Of course the title of your last question is suspect "Pre-fill a web page from a web page" ;)

Comment: Well, it did create a new question instead of overwriting my existing one, so that's good.  Now when I click "Ask Question", it displays my latest question in the form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

It will not overwrite your previous question. Most likely what happens here is that you had your previous question open in two windows (started it, opened a new question tab that was then prefilled), submitted one and closed the other. Your question then is still cached and will appear the next time you open a new question form.

I have this happen with a mild amount of regularity when I have multiple tabs open.

Comment: I think this might be a little weirder than that.  This cache has survived a logout/login and a reboot now.  (Last night, I logged out, but the cached question thing persisted today, so I just rebooted my machine, went straight to stackoverflow | ask question, and I still get the cached question.  cookie maybe?)

Comment: I'll get dirty forms on a different machine. All you have to do is have it up in a tab for a while and not submit it. It's a server side cache

Comment: I follow you now.  I did have that question up for a while before I posted it.  Weird that even after almost 18 hours, it's still cached.